# High error due to resample function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, wavelet-transform

I am working on training the output of the wavelet transform of a signal using a neural network in MATLAB. So I decided to use `3` layer `db4` wave filter for its wavelet transform. I have used an array of `240` elements and after wavelet transform, I get an array `l`

```
l = [36;36;65;123;240]
```

Now, since I have to train my neural network, I have to resample the wavelet transforms of length `36, 36, 65, 123` to an array of 240 elements.

So what I did was, I did wavelet transform of the signal. I resampled each wavelet transform to `240` points, and then resampled the wavelet to `36, 36, 65, 123` points respectively. I got an error of `20.2668`. What can be done to reduce error?

I used the following command to resample using MATLAB:

```
[c1, l] = wavedec(signal, 3, 'db4');

c1a = c1(1:l(1));
c1a = resample(c1a, length(signal), length(c1a));

c1b = c1(1+l(1):l(1)+l(2));
c1b = resample(c1b, length(signal), length(c1b));

c1c = c1(1+l(1)+l(2):l(1)+l(2)+l(3));
c1c = resample(c1c, length(signal), length(c1c));

c1d = c1(1+l(1)+l(2)+l(3):l(1)+l(2)+l(3)+l(4));
c1d = resample(c1d, length(signal), length(c1d));

c2a = resample(c1a, l(1), length(c1a));
c2b = resample(c1b, l(2), length(c1b));
c2c = resample(c1c, l(3), length(c1c));
c2d = resample(c1d, l(4), length(c1d));

X = waverec([c2a; c2b; c2c; c2d], l, 'db4');
err = norm(X-signal)
```

Now, the error err is reported as

```
err = 20.26688
```

What can I do to reduce this error? 
Please help :)

The data plot for wavelet transform after both resampling and original is: [image: Image showing both the original and resampled signals]

Comment: Why do you have to resample wavelets to 240. please explain more I'm not familiar with NN

Comment: @Katmal: Actually I am having a data of price and demand. So I did wavelet transform of price. Now after wavelet transform, I have to train a neural network for each of the series obtained by wavelet transform, which takes demand as the input, and gives price as the output. So I need to convert each series to 240 element series, as I have a demand array of 240 elements.

Comment: @Kamtal: I think waverec accepts both a row and a column wise vector. I don't get this error. This is because they all are column vectors.  X = waverec([c2a', c2b', c2c', c2d'], l, 'db4')';
err = norm(X-price1). This also returns the same error as 20.2668.

Comment: I think that your data has lots of high frequency components. Is order of samples important for you?

Comment: @Kamtal: Each signal depends on some of the previous signals.

Comment: Are high frequency components important for you? if not you could use `smooth` at first, I tried it and it halved `err`

Comment: If you share a plot of data it would help a lot.

Comment: @Kamtal: I have shared the same.

Comment: A question. You want to resample the wavelet coefficients to 240 so they will represent a feature of data, right? for example `c1a(212)` be a feature for `signal(212)`? If that is what you are trying to do, then It's not right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to resample all wavelet coefficients to your signal length, `240`, and then use them as features for a classification, as far as I know, that is wrong because wavelet coefficients are like frequency components and you can't assign them to time domain samples.

What I suggest is to reconstruct your signal with different combinations of wavelet coefficients, so you would have a signal in time domain, then you could use it as feature.

I provided an example,

```
X = sin(rand(1,240)).*sin(5*linspace(0,2*pi,240));
subplot(5,1,1)
plot (X); title ('Original Signal');
[C, L] = wavedec(X, 3, 'db4');
C1 = C; C2 = C; C3 = C; C4 = C;
C1(L(1)+1:end) = 0;
X1 = waverec(C1, L, 'db4');
subplot(5,1,2)
plot(X1);title ('A3');
C2(1:L(1)) = 0;
C2(L(1)+L(2)+1:end) = 0;
X2 = waverec(C2, L, 'db4');
subplot(5,1,3)
plot(X2); title ('D3');
C3(1:L(1)+L(2)) = 0;
C3(L(1)+L(2)+L(3)+1:end) = 0;
X3 = waverec(C3, L, 'db4');
subplot(5,1,4)
plot(X3); title ('D2');
C4(1:L(1)+L(2)+L(3)) = 0;
C4(L(1)+L(2)+L(3)+L(4)+1:end) = 0;
X4 = waverec(C4, L, 'db4');
subplot(5,1,5)
plot(X4); title ('D1');
```

Gives `4` signals all with length `240` *which can be used as features.*

[image]